Domain of the bayesian parameter as a random variable
In bayesian statistics, they consider the parameter as a random variable.
And random variable is a measurable function from a probability space $\Omega$ to real line.
Then, what is that probability space? For example, suppose we are to estimate the probability $\theta$ of the head of the coin $A$ in coin flipping. Let us assume that $\theta$ follows Beta distribution as a prior.
So $\theta$ is a function which takes the range $[0,1]$. But what is a domain of $\theta$?
My (somewhat very unmathematical) guess was that the domain is the set of infinitely many coins, physically perfectly identical to coin $A = A_0$, including coin $A_0$ itself, i.e.
$$\Omega = \{\text{coin} \ A_i \ | \ i \in \mathbb{R}\}.$$
Each coin $A_i$ has its own probability of getting head, and this probability is represented as $\theta(\text{coin} \ A_i)$.
Those were just my guess, and any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Welcome new user. Please add Mathjax to improve your question to MSE quality guidelines. Here is a tutorial link: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference
